# am I misunderstanding boundness of a transformation?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach's space $Y$ a normed vector space $H\in B(X,Y)$ a family of bounded linear transformations $X\rightarrow Y$ and $V_n:=\{x\in X:\exists T\in H$ such that $||Tx||>n \}  n\in \mathbb{N}$

If $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V_N$ isn't dense then $\sup_{T\in H}||T||<\infty$

I'm not sure how to relate density with $T$'s finiteness, I had the idea that $T$ being bounded gave
 $$\sup_{T\in H}||T||<\infty$$ automatically.

Comment: $T$ being bounded gives $T \in B(X,Y)$, equivalently $\lVert T\rVert < +\infty$. $\sup\limits_{T\in H} \lVert T\rVert < +\infty$ means $H$ is bounded (in $B(X,Y)$).